# R Derivatives of an Inverse

Tags: r, derivative

I have an expression that contains several parts. However, for simplicity, consider only the following part as MWE:

Let's assume we have the inverse of a matrix `Y` that I want to differentiate w.r.t. `x`.

`Y` is given as `I - (x * b * t(b))`, where `I` is the identity matrix, `x` is a scalar, and `b` is a vector.

According to [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) Equ. 59, the partial derivative of an inverse is:
[image]

Normally I would use the function `D` from the package `stats` to calculate the derivatives. But that is not possible in this case, because e.g. `solve` to specify `Y` as inverse and `t()` is not in the table of derivatives.

What is the best workaround to circumvent this problem? Are there any other recommended packages that can handle such input?

Example that doesn't work:

```
f0 <- expression(solve(I - (x * b %*% t(b))))
D(f0, "x")
```

Example that works:

```
f0 <- expression(x^3)
D(f0, "x")
3 * x^2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the question is how to get an explicit expression for the derivative of the inverse of Y with respect to x.  In the first section we compute it and in the second section we double check it by computing it numerically and show that the two approaches give the same result.

b and the null space of b are both eigenspaces of Y which we can readily verify by noting that Yb = (1-(b'b)x)b and if z belongs to the nullspace of b then Yz = z. This also shows that the corresponding eigenvalues are 1 - x(b'b) with multiplicity 1 and 1 with multiplicity n-1 (since the nullspace of b has that dimension).

As a result of the fact that we can expand such a matrix into the sum of each eigenvalue times the projection onto its eigenspace we can express Y as the following where bb'/b'b is the projection onto the eigenspace spanned by b and the part pre-multiplying it is the eigenvalue.  The remaining terms do not involve x because they involve an eigenvalue of 1 independently of x and the nullspace of b is independent of x as well.

```
Y = (1-x(b'b))(bb')/(b'b) + terms not involving x
```

The inverse of Y is formed by taking the reciprocals of the eigenvalues so:

```
Yinv = 1/(1-x(b'b)) * (bb')/(b'b) + terms not involving x
```

and the derivative of that wrt x is:

```
(b'b) / (1 - x(b'b))^2 * (bb')/(b'b)
```

Cancelling the b'b and writing the derivative in terms of R code:

```
1/(1 - x*sum(b*b))^2*outer(b, b)
```

### Double check

Using specific values for b and x we can verify it against the numeric derivative as follows:

```
library(numDeriv)

x <- 1
b <- 1:3

# Y inverse as a function of x
Yinv <- function(x) solve(diag(3) - x * outer(b, b))

all.equal(matrix(jacobian(Yinv, x = 1), 3), 
          1/(1 - x*sum(b*b))^2*outer(b, b))
## [1] TRUE
```